# FloatingActionButton has strange background in API 19

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

### My FloatingActionButton works well in API 20+, but on API 19 I have this strange circle behind it.

[image]

You can see **around the orange circle there is another rounded rectangle** or I don't really know what is that... but it is there.

How could I hide that thing?

This **only appears on API 19 (Android 4.4)**

I use `'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'`

Thanks in advance.

**E D I T:**

I don't use elevation.

**XML source:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/stream_toggle_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_stream_video_white" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml here

Comment: I believe you are giving elevation to your fab button. Elevation doesn't work below lollipop devices :)

Comment: @AntonA. See my edit

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi FAB shoud be use either in RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.

Comment: @AntonA. *`FAB shoud be use either in RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.`* Can u explain **`WHY`**

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi because it has shadow, linear layout ignore it and wrap content. You can use it in Linear, but it has to be one element to display correctly

Comment: @AntonA. You are right, add this as an answer.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi provided my answear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAB is using shadow, `LinearLayout` not suitable for, because it wrap view content and ignore fab shadow.

FAB should be in `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` (most suitable) or `CoordinatorLayout`. Wich as parent of FAB and main layout of view not wrap FAB size.

**Basic usage of FAB in those is** -

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks.

Part two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243882/extra-marginspacing-around-floatingactionbutton-only-on-api-19