# Extra margin(spacing) around FloatingActionButton only on API 19

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I'm experiencing an e**xtra margin or spacing around FloatingActionButton** but only on API19.

**Screenshot on API19:**

[image]

Margin is **correct on every other version,** see screenshot below:

[image]

The developer option for **showing layout boundaries is turned on in both cases.** You can clearly see that in API 19 there is an extra space around the FABs.

**XML:**

```
      <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/path_btn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:background="@null"
                            app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_light"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_line" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/stream_toggle_btn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/path_btn"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:background="@null"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_stream_video_white" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please consider that the **margins in the XML only adds the purple area** on the screenshots. If I remove the margins the extra spacing does not disappear.

Please help if you can.

Thanks.

**E D I T:**

Adding

```
  app:useCompatPadding="true"
```

To FABS does not help. Spacing still there.

Comment: Try setting `app:useCompatPadding="false"` .

Comment: @ADM Sadly does not help. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *`programmatically`* remove *`margin`* from *`floatingActionButton`* like.It is a known issue and it is because of extra margin.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) stream_toggle_btn.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    stream_toggle_btn.setLayoutParams(params);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) path_btn.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    path_btn.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**EDIT**

Try to use this properties inside *`FloatingActionButton`* `xml`.

```
app:elevation="0dp"
app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
```

Like

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/path_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@null"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_light"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_line"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Sadly does not help. Space still remains.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi Did you tried my updated answer is it worked for you ??

Answer (score 2):

This is because special padding implementation in the FAB on pre-Lollipop devices.

You can use

```
app:useCompatPadding="true"
```

to override this behavior.

> boolean: true if FloatingActionButton is adding inner padding on
>   platforms Lollipop and after, to ensure consistent dimensions on all
>   platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Set `app:useCompatPadding="true"` for the fab if you want the same padding for all android versions

Comment: I know this doesn't solve the problem. This is android's problem and hasn't been solved yet. This is just the way to make the fab having the same margin in newer versions so that you don't encounter different appearance due to different versions.

Comment: aaaahh, so it does add extra spacing on newer versions instead of removing it on older ones, right?

Answer (score 0):

For those who use material floating action button with

```
app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/your_size"
```

to get rid from extra padding around FAB, you can override dimension that comes from material library. Just put this line to your dimen.xml

```
<dimen name="mtrl_fab_min_touch_target" tools:override="true">@dimen/your_size</dimen>
```

Before
[image]

After
[image]